# An issue with IDE in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling, ide

I have been recently encountering issues when trying to start a new Project in Android Studio.
 i always get this error message when i attempt to create a new blank activity, I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio, making a new bin file with the "disable.android.first.run=true" code and replacing the original one, and also as well as Invalidating/Replacing cache.

I am at a loss on what to do and need help in solving this issue.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:173)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:249)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.compute(WriteCommandAction.java:137)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewModuleModel$ModuleTemplateRenderer.render(NewModuleModel.kt:195)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.MultiTemplateRenderer$countDown$2.invoke(MultiTemplateRenderer.kt:132)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.MultiTemplateRenderer$countDown$2.invoke(MultiTemplateRenderer.kt:37)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModel$multiTemplateRenderer$1$$special$$inlined$run$lambda$1$1.run(NewProjectModel.kt:111)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.NonProjectFileWritingAccessProvider.disableChecksDuring(NonProjectFileWritingAccessProvider.java:174)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModel$multiTemplateRenderer$1$$special$$inlined$run$lambda$1.invoke(NewProjectModel.kt:110)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModel$multiTemplateRenderer$1$$special$$inlined$run$lambda$1.invoke(NewProjectModel.kt:89)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidNewProjectInitializationStartupActivity.runActivity(AndroidNewProjectInitializationStartupActivity.kt:41)
at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runActivity(StartupManagerImpl.java:205)
```

More Details

```
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.intellij.xml.arrangement.XmlArrangementVisitor.createNewEntry(XmlArrangementVisitor.java:94)
at com.intellij.xml.arrangement.XmlArrangementVisitor.visitXmlTag(XmlArrangementVisitor.java:52)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlTagImpl.accept(XmlTagImpl.java:1040)
at com.intellij.xml.arrangement.XmlArrangementVisitor.visitXmlFile(XmlArrangementVisitor.java:45)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlFileImpl.accept(XmlFileImpl.java:71)
at com.intellij.xml.arrangement.XmlRearranger.parse(XmlRearranger.java:128)
at com.intellij.psi.codeStyle.arrangement.engine.ArrangementEngine$Context.from(ArrangementEngine.java:525)
at com.intellij.psi.codeStyle.arrangement.engine.ArrangementEngine.arrange(ArrangementEngine.java:117)
at com.intellij.psi.codeStyle.arrangement.engine.ArrangementEngine.arrange(ArrangementEngine.java:78)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.TemplateUtils.reformatAndRearrange(TemplateUtils.kt:206)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.TemplateUtils.reformatAndRearrange$default(TemplateUtils.kt:183)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.TemplateUtils$reformatAndRearrange$1.run(TemplateUtils.kt:153)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$runWriteCommandAction$5(WriteCommandAction.java:368)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl$1.run(WriteCommandAction.java:125)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:35)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$null$1(WriteCommandAction.java:264)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:994)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$performWriteCommandAction$2(WriteCommandAction.java:263)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$doExecuteCommand$4(WriteCommandAction.java:320)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:212)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:188)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.doExecuteCommand(WriteCommandAction.java:322)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:263)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:245)


at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.run(WriteCommandAction.java:127)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:368)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:360)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.TemplateUtils.reformatAndRearrange(TemplateUtils.kt:145)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.lambda$render$1(Template.java:267)
at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.lambda$runWhenProjectIsInitialized$7(StartupManagerImpl.java:499)
at com.intellij.ui.GuiUtils.invokeLaterIfNeeded(GuiUtils.java:323)
at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runWhenProjectIsInitialized(StartupManagerImpl.java:485)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.render(Template.java:267)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewModuleModel$ModuleTemplateRenderer.renderModule(NewModuleModel.kt:220)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewModuleModel$ModuleTemplateRenderer.access$renderModule(NewModuleModel.kt:140)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewModuleModel$ModuleTemplateRenderer$render$success$1.compute(NewModuleModel.kt:196)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewModuleModel$ModuleTemplateRenderer$render$success$1.compute(NewModuleModel.kt:140)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl$2.run(WriteCommandAction.java:135)


at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:35)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$null$1(WriteCommandAction.java:264)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:994)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$performWriteCommandAction$2(WriteCommandAction.java:263)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$doExecuteCommand$4(WriteCommandAction.java:320)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:220)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:188)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.doExecuteCommand(WriteCommandAction.java:322)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:263)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$execute$0(WriteCommandAction.java:249)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransactionAndWait$2(TransactionGuardImpl.java:161)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:82)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:106)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:433)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:416)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:399)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:878)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:466)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:693)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:465)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.pumpEventsForHierarchy(IdeEventQueue.java:935)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:205)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:191)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ApplicationImpl.java:566)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:459)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ProgressManagerImpl.java:82)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:256)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:210)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.loadProjectUnderProgress(ProjectManagerImpl.java:484)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.lambda$openProject$9(ProjectManagerImpl.java:398)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:82)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:148)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.openProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:439)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModel$multiTemplateRenderer$1.invoke(NewProjectModel.kt:114)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModel$multiTemplateRenderer$1.invoke(NewProjectModel.kt:89)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.MultiTemplateRenderer.countDown(MultiTemplateRenderer.kt:123)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.MultiTemplateRenderer.skipRender(MultiTemplateRenderer.kt:111)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.RenderTemplateModel.handleSkipped(RenderTemplateModel.kt:104)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.handleFinished(ModelWizard.java:408)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.goForward(ModelWizard.java:330)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizardDialog$FinishAction.doAction(ModelWizardDialog.java:313)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1821)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6550)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6315)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4899)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
```

More Details

```
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:878)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:823)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:466)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:693)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:465)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1077)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:707)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:432)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1685)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1644)
at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidNewProjectAction.actionPerformed(AndroidNewProjectAction.kt:45)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:265)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:282)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:292)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:265)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:107)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:282)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:82)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:106)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:115)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:121)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:524)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:35)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:546)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6550)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6315)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4899)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
```

More Details

```
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:878)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:823)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:466)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:704)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:465)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your Android studio cache also go to user folder and clean .Gradle cache folder and use good VPN to build your project